# Software crashes in production environment, no access to debugger. What to do in short-term and long-term?

Tags: testing, crash

This is an interview question:

Software crashes in production environment, no access to debugger. What steps would you do to solve the problem short term? Long term? What would you do to prevent it from happening? What tools would you use?

My ideas:

Short term:

- Track the log file of the program generate by OS, which may generate some signals about the crash.
- Narrow down to the file where the program crashes by adding some print.
- Add try-catch in the possible locations.
- Find the reason.

Long-term:

- Check the whole program design idea, algorithm/data structure usage, to make sure that they are used correctly and suitably.
- Test it with different cases that have caused crashes to find the essential reasons
- Tools : GDB, Valgrind family, gprof

Any better ideas or solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short Term
 1. The absolute first thing to do is work out what was done to generate the problem and try and reproduce it.  If you can do that, you can now track it down in a debugged environment.
 2. If it is not reproducible, you need to look through all the information you collected in step one (which will include any logging) and see if you can see a possible problem.
 3. If the problem has not been found, you will need to add logging, and lots of it.  This is where a "DEBUG" logging setting comes in handy.  It will probably slow down the system, and may even mask the problem (which tells you something about the nature of the problem).
 4. With the new logging information you can go back to step one.  Repeat this until the problem is solved!

In the long term the most obvious thing to do is make sure you have sufficient logging in place, even if it has to be turned on and off, to catch problems.  As well as this, you need to try and beef up the testing effort..

When you have tracked down a problem, it is worth noting the type of problem (race condition, scalability, database access, etc.).  This gives you an area to apply more automated and manual tests.

Comment: how to reproduce the problem is a key point, what I can get now is to add print() to the program to track the program. Are there better ways ?

Comment: I would rather fprintf to a file.  Step one is probably to put a message at the start of each function/method.  Then narrow in from there.

Answer (score 1):

You have some good initial ideas, here are my comments:

1. Add logging to your code - you will get very little information from
   the operating system about your code.
2. If exceptions can be thrown by methods that you call, you should catch them. Don't let them bubble up to the end user!
3. Run valgrind now, not later
4. Setup a test environment that simulates your production environment. Start simple, and increase the complexity until you are able to reproduce your issue. You do have a test environment, right?

Comment: if no debug tools can be used, I add logging by print ? About test, i need to design input for different cases and run it ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "no debug tools", but logging via printf to a file or using something like log4j is what I had in mind.

Comment: suppose gdb, or other similar tools are not allowed to use.

Comment: In that case, you want a human-readable text file. Be careful not to dump too much data into it too quickly, or you will fill up the disk. But don't be afraid of plain-text log files as service debugging aids. They are fast and easy to use, and won't add any noticeable load to your service.

Answer (score 1):

The very first thing you should do is ***determine the severity of the problem***. This will help to devise your short-term strategy. You will need to have some brief discussions with the major stakeholders in the software (such as the client), or have a project manager do this and report back to you.

In the heat of the moment, this is often the bit overlooked, and rushing a short-term fix almost always means wasting a lot of time not really understanding what needs to be done.

After this, your actual strategy, both long term and short term, is rather dependent on the technology you are using and how it is deployed.

**Short term**

It is absolutely vital to grab some preliminary information about the crash before attempting to resolve the problem, grab log files, take screenshots, note down system info like memory/CPU usage, archive any temporary data that might be useful.

The short-term action should be to get the system up-and-running again, quickly. Some common approaches to short-term solutions:

- Try turning it off and on again... Seriously, 90% of the time this
  will get production running again in the short term, at least until
  the bug manifests itself again.
- Revert to a previous production
  release, preferably the latest version that was known to work fairly
  reliably.
- Run a second instance on another machine and fail-over if
  the problem occurs again. This has the added bonus that logs and
  system state are preserved after the last crash occurred.

**Long term**

In the long term, you will want to properly analyse the information you gathered at the time of failure. Where possible, try to reproduce the problem as closely as you can. Revert your code to the version being deployed (you do use version control tools right?), check high-level factors as well as low-level configuration ones. e.g. who was using the system when it crashed? Can they show you what they did?

Debugging and logging may be useful at this stage, and all the usual developer tools such as functional tests and memory profiling tools. A crash could come from a number of sources, from memory protection faults to an unexpected state of a resource. You should compile a list of candidate problems, and cross them off as you gain confidence that they aren't the cause of the crash.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from logging, you can enable creation of mdmp files ( windows ) or the core dumps ( linux ) then examine them later; One downside of this approach is that core dumps can be pretty big. mdmp and core dumps contain the context of the application when the crash occurred.